# Simple C# Excel Add-In Ribbon Button to Color Cells

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, excel-2007, excel-addins

First, a big thank you to anyone that read this question and can help.

I'm sing VS2010 and I've created a Excel 2007 Add-In Project using the wizard, then I added a new folder to my project called Ribbon, and inside it created a New Item which is a Ribbon (Visual Designer).

From here I've added a new group to the ribbon and a new button. I double clicked on the new button and am presented with this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace UploadFCStats.Ribbon
{
    public partial class FCRibbon
    {
        private void FCRibbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Now all I want to do is color some cells, or store some values in variables, and then create a connection to a SQL server and use an insert statement to upload some data.

However I can't seem to access any of the typical Excel properties. Now I am new at C# and Excel Add-In's but have a great understanding of C++, Java, and Excel. Nothing I've googled has helped me in this instance.

My best guess is that I'm missing a library, but after some fiddling that didn't seem to solve my problem. Using this button, how do I grab values from the worksheet? How do I color cells? How do I access formula functions inside of excel?

Thank you!

Comment: Check this link: http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-read-excel.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read some basics about creating an Excel 2007 Add-In and start with [Globals.ThisAddIn.Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157876.aspx)

Comment: Yep I am having no problem accessing the objects from the ThisAddIn class. I can even reference my own written code from the Ribbon button, so does this mean I cannot reference the Excel objects directly from the Ribbon?

Answer (score 0):

You have to access Range object (i.e. Cells, Rows, Columns) and then change background or anything you want to change.

```
var range = ((Range)Globals.ThisAddin.Application.Cells[1,1]).Resize[1,5];
range.Interior.Color = (int)XlRgbColor.rgbGreen;
```

Casting to Range is unnecessary but Cells[1,1] is type of dynamic. When I cast it to Range intelisence tells me what properties Range has.

Application.Cells[1,1] selects Cell A1, Resize[1,5] resizes range to all cells between A1 and E1 including these.